# Как сортировать записи в БД?

Tags: java, база-данных, сортировка

Java-приложение на стеке `Hibernate`, `Spring MVC`.

Есть пользователь, у которого есть список задач. Например:

```
Покушать
Убраться
Выгулять собаку
Купить еды
Почистить зубы
```

Мне необходимо сделать настраиваемую сортировку этих событий. Наверху самые приоритетные задачи, внизу второстепенные. Пользователь должен иметь возможность провести следующие операции с каждой задачей:

- Поднять на 1 наверх
- Поднять на самых верх
- Опустить на 1 вниз
- Опустить в самый низ

Изначально я планировал использовать специальное сортировочное число. То есть сделать вот так:

```
Покушать         500
Убраться         400
Выгулять собаку  300
Купить еды       200
Почистить зубы   100
```

Но такой подход создаёт очень много телодвижений. В частности, чтобы опустить запись на 1, мне придётся считывать весь список, находить соседнюю запись, вытаскивать её сортировочное число, менять местами сортировочное число в опускаемой записи с числом из её соседки, а потом записывать всё это обратно.

Существует ли какой-то более адекватный альтернативный вариант? Возможно, существуют библиотеки для облегчения сортировки?

Answer (score -1):

```
        dbFuelbase = new Fuelbase(getApplicationContext());
        database = dbFuelbase.getWritableDatabase();
        cursor = database.query(Fuelbase.TABLE_FUEL, null, selection, null, null, null, "fuel_probeg DESC");
```

Обратите внимание на последнюю часть чтения базы. fuel_probeg это имя столбца, который вы сортируете. DESC или ASC это уменьшение или возрастание. И получаете таблицу, сортированную по этому столбцу.
selection это у меня выборка данных. Думаю вам тоже пригодится. Изучите запрос чтения данных. Литературы много.

Если у вас нет базы данных, сделайте её. Это облегчит вашу задачу